# How to trigger a method from an observable that is out of scope

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a ListView that changes. This ListView is inside LinearLayout that also has an Icon that shows as a checkmark if the ListView items include an item of a certain type. It shows an "X" if none of the items are of that type.

In the code below, the Console.WriteLine works.

How do I update the Icon (aka call the Redraw function) after a NotifyDataSetChanged has been called on the ListView adapter. The function is outside of the scope of the observer and cannot be called inside the OnChanged.

```
private void Init () {
    view = ((Activity)cx).LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyPage, this);

    eventsListAdapter?.Dispose();
    eventsListAdapter = new EventsAdapter(
        context,
        EventListDisplay.DefaultView,
        dateCurrentlyDisplayed);

    var myObserver = new MyDataSetObserver();
    eventsListAdapter.RegisterDataSetObserver(myObserver);
}

private void Redraw () {
    // UPDATE ICON HERE
}

public class MyDataSetObserver : DataSetObserver
{
    public override void OnChanged()
    {
        base.OnChanged();
        Console.WriteLine("Change was observerd");


        OnDataChanged(new DataChangedEventArgs() { DataChanged = 1, TimeChanged = DateTime.Now });

        // This area is hit, but how do I call the Redraw method above? It is out of scope
    }
}
```

/// EDIT: Something I've Tried THAT WORKS! Anything seem off about it?

```
private void Init () {
    view = ((Activity)cx).LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyPage, this);

    eventsListAdapter?.Dispose();
    eventsListAdapter = new EventsAdapter(
        context,
        EventListDisplay.DefaultView,
        dateCurrentlyDisplayed);

    var myObserver = new MyDataSetObserver();
    eventsListAdapter.RegisterDataSetObserver(myObserver);

    myObserver.DataChanged += OnDataChanged;
}

private void Redraw () {
    // UPDATE ICON HERE
}

private void OnDataChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Redraw();
}

// Added the last four event handler pieces
public class MyDataSetObserver : DataSetObserver
    {
        public override void OnChanged()
        {
            base.OnChanged();
            g.ToastShort("Change was observerd");
        }

        public event EventHandler DataChanged;

        protected virtual void OnDataChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler handler = DataChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        public delegate void DataChangedEventHandler(object sender, DataChangedEventArgs e);

        public class DataChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public int DataChanged { get; set; }
            public DateTime TimeChanged { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the DatasetObserver object but if OnChanged causes and event to fire bind to that event after creation and have it run your method.  I'm assuming init and Redraw are in the same scope.  If OnChanged doesn't cause an event to fire youll need to create one in your MyDataSetObserver class and fire it.

Comment: @Tyddlywink, I looked up adding Events and have implemented in my edit above. Does anything about how I've implemented that seem bad practice? It is successfully triggering my Redraw function :)

Comment: That'll do'er.   Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Tyddlywink for your comment: "youll need to create [an Event] in your MyDataSetObserver class and fire it"

I used this as a resource for adding Events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/

Here are the updates I added to trigger my Redraw() function:

```
private void Init () {
    view = ((Activity)cx).LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyPage, this);

    eventsListAdapter?.Dispose();
    eventsListAdapter = new EventsAdapter(
        context,
        EventListDisplay.DefaultView,
        dateCurrentlyDisplayed);

    var myObserver = new MyDataSetObserver();
    eventsListAdapter.RegisterDataSetObserver(myObserver);

    myObserver.DataChanged += OnDataChanged;
}

private void Redraw () {
    // UPDATE ICON HERE
}

private void OnDataChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Redraw();
}

public class MyDataSetObserver : DataSetObserver
    {
        public override void OnChanged()
        {
            base.OnChanged();

            // To be honest, I don't know what int DataChanged wants.. so arbitrarily set it to 1.
            OnDataChanged(new DataChangedEventArgs() { DataChanged = 1, TimeChanged = DateTime.Now });
        }

        public event EventHandler DataChanged;

        protected virtual void OnDataChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler handler = DataChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        public delegate void DataChangedEventHandler(object sender, DataChangedEventArgs e);

    public class DataChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int DataChanged { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeChanged { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [messaging-center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to notify your activity to call `Redraw()` when `OnChanged` hit.

> The MessagingCenter is a simple way to reduce coupling, especially
>   between view models. It can be used to send and receive simple
>   messages or pass an argument between classes. Classes should
>   unsubscribe from messages they no longer wish to receive.

In the `OnChanged()`, send a message every time it is hit:

```
  public override void OnChanged()
        {
            base.OnChanged();
            Console.WriteLine("Change was observerd");

            // This area is hit, but how do I call the Redraw method above? It is out of scope

            MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "needRedraw");

        }
```

In your `Init()`, Subscribe the `needRedraw` message and call redraw whenever the "needRedraw" message is sent:

```
private void Init()
        {
            view = ((Activity)cx).LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyPage, this);

            eventsListAdapter?.Dispose();
            eventsListAdapter = new EventsAdapter(
                context,
                EventListDisplay.DefaultView,
                dateCurrentlyDisplayed);

            var myObserver = new MyDataSetObserver();
            eventsListAdapter.RegisterDataSetObserver(myObserver);

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "needRedraw", (sender) => {
                // do something whenever the "needRedraw" message is sent
                Redraw();
            });
        }
```

Comment: This sounds perfect, hmm.. but I am not using Xamarin Forms

Comment: @SweetTomato This is also available in Xamarin.Android. And in Xamarin.Android, you can use [broadcast-receivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers) to achieve that, the same as messagingcenter.

Comment: I tried implementing this solution and couldn't find the correct using statement then? in order for my application to recognize the MessagingCenter

Comment: @SweetTomato Install xamarin.forms nugget package in your project.